# Anti Join with group/conditions

Tags: mysql, left-join

Note: I have simplified the question since both that and the answer have become I believe more complex than intended.

I want to an an anti-join that has a condition other than just not existing in the first table.

### Table Product / Manufacturer

- Widget /  Acme
- Paddle / Acme
- Ball / Acme
- Gas / Exxon
- Pump / Exxon

### Table: Customer / Product

- Karen / Ball
- Bob / Paddle
- Karen / Gas
- Bob / Pump

A "normal" anti-join would find out which products have not been ordered via

```
Select Products from `Product / Manufacturer` as T1
Left Join `Customer / Product` as T2 
On T2.Zip is NULL
```

However what I am looking for is which customers didn't order which products, in essence:

```
Select Products from `Product / Manufacturer` 
where Manufacturer = 'Acme' that do not exist in `Customer / Product` 
where Customer = 'Karen'
```

and

```
Select Products from `Product / Manufacturer` 
where Manufacturer = 'Exxon' that do not exist in `Customer / Product` 
where Customer = 'Karen'
```

and

```
Select Products from `Product / Manufacturer` 
where Manufacturer = 'Acme' that do not exist in `Customer / Product` 
where Customer = 'Bob'
```

and

```
Select Products from `Product / Manufacturer` 
where Manufacturer = 'Exxon' that do not exist in `Customer / Product` 
where Customer = 'Bob'
```

'
But as one query since there are 100s of "Customers" and 100s of Manufacturers.

Comment: please add the expected output for this given set of data.

Comment: can you share the expected output.

Comment: @1000111 I updated the fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa700e/3

Comment: @Sang I updated the fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa700e/3

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *exclude* all products for a manufacturer for which no product from that manufacturer appears in any order...

Then that means that you only want to *include* only products from certain manufacturers...

Which manufacturers have had a product appear in an order ?

```
SELECT r.manufacturer 
  FROM products r
  JOIN orders s
    ON s.product = r.product
 GROUP BY r.manufacturer
```

You can wrap that query in parens and include it as an inline view ...

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM ( SELECT r.manufacturer 
           FROM product r
           JOIN orders s
             ON s.product = r.product
          GROUP BY r.manufacturer
       ) q
  JOIN product p 
    ON p.manufacturer = q.manufacturer
  LEFT
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.product = p.Product 
 WHERE o.product IS NULL
```

There are other query patterns that will return an equivalent result.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

NOTE: The "breakdown by gender/hour" part wasn't made clear in the original specification.

The query pattern is very much the same. Use an inline view query to return a distinct list of manufacturers for each gender/hour.

Then join that set to the product table, to get every product from those  manufacturer. That will included products that were ordered, as well as products that weren't ordered.

Then apply the anti-join pattern, to exclude the products that were ordered by gender/hour.

```
SELECT q.gender
     , q.hour
     , p.manufacturer
     , p.product
  FROM ( SELECT s.gender
              , s.hour
              , r.manufacturer
           FROM orders s
           JOIN product r
             ON r.product = s.product
          GROUP
             BY s.gender
              , s.hour
              , r.manufacturer
       ) q
  JOIN product p
    ON p.manufacturer = q.manufacturer
  LEFT
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.gender  = q.gender
   AND o.hour    = q.hour
   AND o.product = p.product
 WHERE o.product IS NULL
```

---

If that's not clear, consider that the following query returns an equivalent set.  The inline line view query `t` returns the set of all products from a manufacturer, by gender/hour.

This query is somewhat less efficient (at least in MySQL) due to the additional inline view.  And while longer, it may be more understandable, since the view query `t` makes explicit the set of all possible rows that could be returned... every product by manufacturer/gender/hour. (To see that set, the view query `t` can be pulled out and run separately to see what it returns.)

In the outermost query, `t` is referenced as if it were a table. If it `t` were replaced by a simple table reference, the query would just be a simple anti-join. All rows from `t` excluding rows that have a match.

```
SELECT t.gender
     , t.hour
     , t.manufacturer
     , t.product
  FROM ( 
         SELECT q.gender
              , q.hour
              , q.manufacturer
              , p.product
           FROM ( SELECT s.gender
                       , s.hour
                       , r.manufacturer
                    FROM orders s
                    JOIN product r
                      ON r.product = s.product
                   GROUP
                      BY s.gender
                       , s.hour
                       , r.manufacturer
                ) q
           JOIN product p
             ON p.manufacturer = q.manufacturer
       ) t
  LEFT
  JOIN orders o
    ON o.gender  = t.gender
   AND o.hour    = t.hour
   AND o.product = t.product
 WHERE o.product IS NULL
```

---

I recommend you get the set of rows returned first. Before you futz  with adding a `GROUP BY` and a `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate to collapse the rows.

If you want to group multiple values of "hour" into just "am" or "pm", you can use an expression (in place of "hour") that returns "am" or "pm". (Think in terms of that expression being another column in the table; but instead of referencing a column in the table, you use an expression that derives the value from other columns in the table.

```
   IF(x.hour<12,'am','pm')
```

Comment: I am trying to get all products that have NOT been ordered only when other prods have been ordered by that Mfctr. I have updated fiddle but the idea is eg Men ordered from McDonalds in the AM McMuffins I want a list of what Men did't order in the am from McDonalds. If they didn't order from BK I don't need that list. If Women ordered from Burger King Fries at Lunch I need a list of what BK Products they did NOT order then. There is grouping going on but the core issue is I need a list of products NOT ordered by a manufacturer only when other products were ordered from the same.

Comment: I added a followup to the original answer, with an example query with a  "breakdown by gender/hour". (In the original question that was asked, that part of the specification is ambiguous, as it's not mentioned. I think this is where an *example* of the *expected output* of the query would help clarify the spec.)

Comment: I modified the layout of the question as I think (hope) while your answer is detailed and much appreciated it may be overkill for what I want as I may not have explained it clearly, I hope this does.

Comment: @user3649739: The update to the question is an improvement. To use the anti-join pattern to get the set you're after, you'll need a rowsource to return the rows that don't exist. I'm certain there are other query patterns that will return the specified resultset. And the examples in my answer do make use of the anti-join pattern as illustrated in the question. I got the part about the "breakdown by gender/hour" from the update to the SQL Fiddle (with gender and hour columns in the demonstration tables). The same pattern could be applied for "customer_name" in place of "gender".